# Firebase - Multiple client apps

Tags: firebase

Does firebase limit the amount of firebase apps that a google account can have? I'm making an app for 2 different customers and have decided to use firebase for the db functionality.

I'm slightly concerned about the above if I were to grow my business. In the event that I manage to increase my client base, , I would hate to have multiple logins to access each client project.

When it comes to billing. Can I set up my firebase to charge my account and not be project specific? An alternative to this would be if I was to create a singular project and then have multiple different apps connect to the database. However I don't think this would be possible as there would be no way for me to know who my **clients** customers would be. Is there anything I'm missing when it comes to this?

Comment: For billing questions, you should contact Firebase support directly, not Stack Overflow.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 0):

There is a fixed limit to how many apps you can have in a single Firebase project. Last I checked it was around 30 or so, but that may have changed.

The important thing to realize is that Firebase projects are meant to cover variants on a single "logical" app, all with a single user-base that all access the same resources.

So if you have an iOS, Android, Unity, Flutter, and Web version of the same app, you'll want to have those in the same project so that they share the same resources. If you have a specific variant of the app for admins, you'll also want to add that to the same project; again, so that it's accessing the same backend resources.

But if you have two different apps with two different user-bases, you should create a separate project for each app.